# While loop definition in python

Tags: python, loops, boolean

My question is about a use of while loops that seems very abstract to me. I understand a while loop like the first one (one which has a clearly defined statement):

```
num = 1
while num<1:
    statement1...
    statement2...
```

but, then there's something like this:

```
num = 1

while num:
    statement...
    statement2....
```

what is the purpose/meaning of `while num:`?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Software Engineering Stack Exchange. I believe that your question is off-topic here, as it belongs to Stack Overflow because it is a question about **Explaining, writing or debugging code**. You can check more about why it is off topic in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and in [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/why-are-implementation-and-debugging-questions-off-topic-on-software-engineering).

Answer (score -5):

because in this case num (having the value 1) evaluates to True.

Try something like:

```
    if x: 
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false") 

print(e(0), e(2), e("a"))
```

Comment: Please, [don't answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8070/6605) questions which are obviously off-topic here, as this encourages other people to post off-topic questions as well.